# Does the kernel or the thread execute a signal/interrupt handler?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, interrupt-handling

I have read that the interrupts/signal handlers are handled in the kernel context. Does this mean that the kernel is executing the code in the signal handler? I find this hard to visualize and was hoping for some clarity regarding the same.

Comment: Part of the problem is that interrupts and signals are completely different things.  Interrupts are generated by hardware (or a process making a system call) and are handled in the kernel.  Signals are a purely software construct, sent by the kernel or by other processes, and the signal handler executes in userspace.

Comment: The "wake up the process" and "interrupting a system call" parts of signal handling is done by the kernel.

Comment: So from what I gather, when an interrupt occurs, the kernel handles it in kernel space. Does the kernel have the concept of "threads"? Or is it just one "kernel thread" that does this work?